# Sequence drop(while:) Seemingly Does Nothing

Tags: swift, collections, range, sequence, swift4

The [Swift Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907425-drop) asserts that:

> **drop(while:)**
>
> Returns a subsequence by skipping elements while predicate returns true and returning the remaining elements.

By using the function signature:

> ```
> func drop(while predicate: (Self.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.SubSequence
> ```

Where `predicate` is described as:

> A closure that takes an element of the sequence as its argument and returns a Boolean value indicating whether the element is a match.

My problem is that, under that description the following behavior shouldn't occur:

```
let test = (0...3).drop { $0 > 1 }
test.contains(0) // true
test.contains(3) // true
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I was really confused by the output I was getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get why you don't understand this behaviour. The documentation is pretty clear and it matches the output.

The documentation says that the method will keep skipping (dropping) elements while the predicate is true. It's like a while loop:

```
// not real code, for demonstration purposes only
while predicate(sequence.first) {
    sequence.dropFirst()
}
```

And the remaining sequence is returned.

For the sequence `0...3`, it's basically `[0, 1, 2, 3]` right?

Does the first element, 0, satisfy the predicate `$0 > 1`? No, so the imaginary while loop breaks, nothing is dropped, so the original sequence is returned.

I think you are confusing this with maybe `prefix`?

With `prefix`, it will keep adding elements to a sequence while the predicate is true and return the sequence when the predicate becomes false.

```
let test = (0...3).prefix { $0 > 1 }
test.contains(0) // false
test.contains(3) // false
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the method dropped elements as it iterated through the entire sequence. Were that the case, $0 would refer to the current element (as is the case with map, filter, reduce, etc.). So while `test.contains(0)` should be true, `test.contains(3)` should be false, right?

Comment: @BrandonBradley I guess the docs isn't so clear here. When I see the signature of the method I immediately think of a while loop dropping the first element of the sequence while the predicate is true though.

Comment: Ah, I now see why the call-site parameter is named while. The method makes much more sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

0 is not greater than 1, so `drop` finishes "dropping" immediately, and returns the whole sequence.

Perhaps you're looking for `filter(_:)` or `prefix(while:)`

Comment: So the method doesn't iterate through the entire sequence?